# Validating multiple forms in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 forms I'd like to validate. For some reason I can only validate one form. Note: In my webpages I use php to include my header file (where the JS validation script is). My question is, what is the proper format to validate multiple forms with the following format?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.onload=function() {
  document.Form1.onsubmit=function() {
        ...
        field validating
        ...
    }
}
```

I've tried this, but only one will work at a time (in this case Form1, since it's first):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.onload=function() {
  document.Form1.onsubmit=function() {
        ...
        field validating
        ...
    }

  document.Form2.onsubmit=function() {
        ...
        field validating
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** This is for an assignment, so it doesn't need to be perfect at all :p

**Edit 2:** HTML Forms:

```
Table1.php
...
<form name="Form1" id="Form1" method="post" onSubmit="return(validate())">
...
Table2.php
...
<form name="Form2" id="Form2" method="post" onSubmit="return(validate())">
...
```

Obviously it's the onSubmit part that is causing the problem?

Comment: PS: validate with the server as well.

Comment: Can you share the HTNL for the forms?

Comment: Can you share the HTNL for the forms?

Comment: @takinola Sorry! I have added them in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onsubmit` to set handler for both, pass this as argument for referencing submitting form

```js
function validate(ele) {
  var valid = true;

  // validate fields
  ele.text.style.borderColor = ele.text.value == '' ? 'red' : 'green'

  return valid;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
  <input name="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />... ...
</form>
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return validate(this);">

  <input name="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />... ...
</form>
```

or you need to get using **[`document.forms[index]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)** with index

```js
console.log(document.forms)

window.onload = function() {
  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
    alert(1);
    // do validation here
  }

  document.forms[1].onsubmit = function() {
    alert(2);
    // do validation here
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
  <input name="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />... ...
</form>
<form id="form2" onsubmit="return validate(this);">

  <input name="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />... ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I do get prompted '1' for every form though. Is there a way I can use the name of the form to identify which is which? These forms are on separate pages by the way.

Comment: @PetShopBoys you can use `this.id` this will prompt id

Comment: Sorry, I meant that form1 prompts '1', and form 2 prompts '1' also, instead of '2'.

Comment: @PetShopBoys if you are talking about first method then use `ele.id` for getting it's id and `ele.name` for getting it's name

Answer (score 0):

Your pointing to undefined properties on the root `document`.  Try using the `document.forms` collection:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

**Example**

`document.forms['formID'].onsubmit`